# Does an interpretation of a structure by itself induce a bijection on the automorphism group of the structure?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $\Gamma$ be a model-theoretic interpretation of a structure $B$ in a structure $A$.  Then $\Gamma$ induces a group homomorphism $\alpha_\Gamma:\mathrm{Aut}(A) \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(B)$. (See, for example, the subsection *The associated functor*, Section 4.3, in *Shorter model theory* by Hodges).

Suppose $B = A$; then $\alpha_\Gamma$ is a map $\mathrm{Aut}(A) \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(A)$.  I suspect that this is bijective.  Is this true?  If so, what are possible hints for a proof of the fact?

Comment: Your terminology is not entirely precise. One does not have an interpretation of one structure in another but rather of one _signature_ in another, subject to conditions etc.

Comment: @ZhenLin could you give me an example?

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, you could talk about interpretations entirely in terms of signatures, but I see no problem in talking about interpretation of one structure in another; indeed, the latter is how Hodges' book defines interpretations.

Comment: Yes, but if you read the part where he actually defines the functor he talks about signatures.

Comment: @ZhenLin Ah, now I see your point.  I should define $\alpha_\Gamma$ in some other way.

Comment: @ZhenLin The question is absolutely meaningful as written.  Any time you have an interpretation (without parameters) of a structure $B$ in a structure $A$, you get the map of automorphism groups in the question. There's no need to say anything about functors to see this. And anyway, part of the data of an interpretation of $B$ in $A$ is an interpretation of the signature of $B$ in the signature of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not true. The idea is that it's possible to interpret a structure $A$ in some smaller part of itself, so that the interpreted copy of $A$ doesn't have all the information about the interpreting copy of $A$.

For example, let $K = \{P_i\mid i\in\omega\}$, all unary predicate symbols, and let $A$ be a countable structure which is partitioned by the $P_i$ into subsets of some equal size $>1$. Let $A'$ be an isomorphic copy of $A$. We interpret $A'$ in $A$ by taking $\text{dom}(A')$ to be defined by $\lnot P_0(x)$ in $A$, and $P_i(x)$ in $A'$ to be defined by $P_{i+1}(x)$ in $A$.

Now the map $\text{Aut}(A) \to \text{Aut}(A')$ induced by this interpretation just takes an automorphism of $A$ and restricts it to the domain of $A'$. This is not injective: its kernel is the permutations of $P_0(A)$ which fix the rest of the structure.